# axios is not prepending default baseUrl in any request even thought it is set

Tags: axios

I set `axios.default.baseUrl` to the api subdomain of a local project. When making requests from the admin subdomain of the site, axios does not prepend the baseUrl.

Instead, it sends the request to admin.example.test (in my case, 'example' is 'loa'. You can see it in the image below).

[image]

How to make axios prepend the default baseUrl in every request? So that I don't have to write something like `axios(axios.defaults.baseUrl + url)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `axios.defaults.baseUrl = "http://api.example.test"`, it should be `axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://api.example.test"`.

I felt kind of stupid for not seeing this. But I will answer my own question because maybe it can help somebody who has the same problem.